# Add filter by required spoken language in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think that would be useful to add a filter in the careers site to filter by spoken language required by the offer itself.

It should be required to the employer to specify the required languages ...

Take a look even at this related [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146749/why-are-job-offers-in-languages-other-than-english-allowed-on-careers) ...

Comment: I like this feature request, but the implementation that comes to mind is kinda weird; "Please tell us which language you have posted this in" being one of the inputs to post a job.  If we had a way to automagically select the correct language it might be more useful.

Comment: @NickLarsen Is that really hard? I mean, a drop-down menu would solve the problem when inputing the job thing.

Comment: @Alenanno it's not hard to put a drop down on a web page, but if you think about it from the perspective of the person filling it out, it like... seriously?  Meta only allows English, but pretend for a moment that it supported multiple languages.  Would you want to tell it what language you are typing in every time you ask or answer a question?

Comment: @NickLarsen I don't know but I suppose that jobs ads are not that regular, no? Just my opinion, though. :)