# Careers: Filter entries by offer's language (French, English etc)

Tags: discussion, jobs, feedback

Related to: [Add filter by required spoken language in Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146753/add-filter-by-required-spoken-language-in-careers)

I think it would be good to filter the job adverts in search not only by "what" and "where" but also "language of the offer".

Rationale: I may want to look for jobs, say, in France, but only for offers written in English. The reasoning is that the language of the offer is the primary language of the work, and someone may not want to work for companies in which the primary language is French, German or whatever.

I don't think adding a dropdown for the poster to choose the language is a crime. Also it can be not so hard to have auto-inferred what the language is based on words used or letters frequency etc.

It could be implemented as a dropdown with English selected by default, and after the user (publisher) pushes the button to post, the language is inferred (locally in JS or remotely via ajax call), if it's different than the value in `<select>`, the notification is shown "We think this offer is in French" and buttons "yes" / "no, it's English".

To avoid choosing this constantly, it can also be a pref in the company's profile.

**Edit:**
Is it really that unimportant for everyone?

Try searching for `java` in `europe`:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java&location=europe&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles

I get results in English, French, German *and Dutch* on the first page. Totally unusable. I have to go through each of the entries to decide if it's of any interest to me.

Perhaps you don't see the problem in the US-centric approach, because it doesn't concern you, but it's a big mess if I want to look for all-european jobs in English.

There is probably a number of people speaking French and German in the whole Europe, but I doubt there are devs speaking Dutch outside of Netherlands and a part of Belgium.

The Dutch offers are kinds of posts that would be closed on SO as "too localized" :)

Comment: By the way, it would be good if the jobs from the Careers banner could also be filtered by language. Perhaps the profile of a (Careers) Stack Overflow user could include a list of known languages. I've seen a Polish ad and I don't know any Polish.

Comment: I searched for this. I agree.